# iptable rule to drop packet with a specific substring in payload

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables

I am trying to write rules to drop any packet, irrespective if it is outgoing, incoming or being forwarded, which has a specific sub string in the TCP or UDP payload.

How am I suppose to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd need a kernel compiled with Netfilter "[String match support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404482/)" enabled.

Then you can

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "test" -j DROP
```

Check the result wth

```
iptables -L
```

Comment: hi, i m using ubuntu kernel 2.6.8.11 kernel. i m trying to write some worm filtering utility on application layer using libpcap library. 
I set the above rules , but still not able to drop packets.

do i need to install string matching support to iptables or is it present by default. is there any way to check it?

Comment: The iptables command would give an error if the module is not present, like "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".  You could use a logging rule to see if the packets match the rule, for example: iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "test" -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix "iptables-string-match"

Comment: iptables -A  appends, you may want to use the -I option to insert at the top of the chain or specify a point to insert the rule; rules are evaluated in order and in some cases it may not produce the results you're expecting.