# block ip addresses that request a specific url

Tags: block, ip-address, iptables

I'm receiving too many requests on my server from different ip addresses. I discovered, watching apache access.log, that all these ip addresses are requesting a specific file (teXeFe.php). I'd like to block the access to all these ip addresses. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using the iptables string match ?

Something like,

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string "teXeFe.php" -j DROP
```

I inserted the rule at position one just for testing since I had other rules that matched before this one if it was insterted furhter down the chain. Anyway, you get the concept. You could also be a little more specific in the rule (including the GET /full/url/path etc).

Here is page describing the string-matching filter, 
- http://spamcleaner.org/en/misc/w00tw00t.html

And here's another stackoverflow-question about it, 
- [iptable rule to drop packet with a specific substring in payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825481/iptable-rule-to-drop-packet-with-a-specific-substring-in-payload)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution did not work for me. Here is what did:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/path/to/file.php" --algo kmp -j REJECT
```